# Executable files not working randomly

Tags: windows-10

Randomly .exe files (specifically ones designed to be called from a command prompt) exit instantly. The latest of which was nano.exe. What's especially weird is that if I have the same .exe in another folder from before it happened, it works 100% fine. If I try and copy and paste the working one over the not-working one it makes no difference. If I copy the not-working one to any other folder, it still does not work. If I paste the not-working file to the folder with the working one (thus replacing the working one), whatever is broken about it comes with it. This happens especially with files created by certutil code, however it sometimes happens to completely regular exes.

**UPDATE**: If I rename the working EXE and copy it to the folder of the non-working one it *works*. It stops working if I change the name to a normal file again. Still just as confused.

I thought it might be a virus or something, but my antivirus sees nothing, and running the `fc` command finds working exes and not-working ones bit-for-bit identical.

Restarting the machine usually fixes the problem, but obviously this is not ideal.

**Other information that may be helpful:**
- Windows 10 Home
- Dell Optiplex 780
- Avast antivirus runing (no alerts when this happens)

Comment: Clearly some other code running on the computer is causing this behavior. Start the machine in clean boot mode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Process Explorer (published by Microsoft, part of Sysinternals) can give lots of visibility about what is going on with processes. Also, checking your Event Viewer seems like a good thing to do here.

Comment: Smart. I have that but hadn’t thought of using it.